# Issues with PHP POST via AJAX within Bootstrap 4 form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, dropdown

I am working on a website for a client which is build upon the free Bootsrap 4 Template called 'agency'. They also provide a simple contact form using a standard Bootstrap Form, which sends the data to a .js File for preprocessing and afterwards the Message gets POSTed (with an AJAX call) to a Server PHP script which actually sends the mail.

**My Problem is: All the Form data is send, except the entries within a Dropdown element.**

One Dropdown example:

```
 <label for="adults">Erwachsene</label>
 <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
    <option value="keine">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
```

1. the Form has no action - as the js. script is invoked as I press submit (default behaviour is prevented)
2. The values of the form are NOT SERIALIZED, they are all collected one-by-one with `$(select#inputID).val()`
3. It does not matter if one uses `document.getElementById(#inputID).value` or any other call
4. The Data is transferred in a standard call:

```
  $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "name": name,
                    "email": email,
                    "street": street,
                    "number": number,
                    "place": place,
                    "postal": postal,
                    "phone": phone,
                    "adults": adults,
                    "children": children,
                    "flat": flat,
                    "startDate": startDate,
                    "endDate": endDate,
                    "dog": dog,
                    "sheets": sheets,
                    "towels": towels,
                    "message": message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success')
                        .html("<div class='alert alert-success'>" +
                            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'></button>" +
                            "<strong>Vielen Dank, Ihre Anfrage wurde verschickt.</strong>" +
                            "</div>");
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'></button>" +
                        "<strong>Sorry, deine Mail konnte nicht versandt werden</strong>" +
                        "</div>");
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
```

5. The php file does nothing than: `$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);` and putting it into the mail body
6. I get the mail and all 'non-dropdown' elements are there
7. console.log() and browser access of the dropdown values works like a charm, so there should be no stupid syntax error or anything (also tried `.toString()`every field before the ajax call)

*Therefore I am uncertain where the error takes place and what the problem is, maybe someone has expierenced a similar situation and has a hint for me.*

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION as recommended in the comments: use getElementById().
I just made a function for getting the dropdown values:

````
function getDDValue(id) {
  let dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
  return dropdown ? dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value : id + " nicht gefunden!";
}

// the call
let adults_value = getDDValue('adults');
```
````

Comment: show us the drop down element.

Comment: `document.getElementById(#inputID).value` is it dropdown value?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks! Sorry, forgot to add it - already edit the post

Comment: @devpro Yeah it is, similar to jQuery's .val() - as I wrote in the post via the browser console and within the script (e.g. console.log()) everything works as I expect it

Comment: so as per your question, you are not getting anything in `document.getElementById("adults").value` right? can u please show your complete ajax request. input and ajax params.

Comment: @devpro of course I get the values but somehow the fields 'disappear' on their way to the mail - insite the .js file I get the expected value of the dropdown inputs. The rest of the ajax call is just a couple more key-value pairs in the data field and the success and failure block

Comment: maybe you are using ID twice "adults"

Comment: @J.Cole As requested, please provide the full ajax call, as well as the PHP code.  Also, check your browser's network inspector to see of the value shows in the request there.

Comment: @PatrickQ - I edit the Post with the full ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get the selected value you should pick it from the option.

```
// get select box object
var adultsSelectBox = document.getElementById("adults");

// get selected option value
var adults = adultsSelectBox.options[adultsSelectBox.selectedIndex].value;

// get selected option text
var adultsText = adultsSelectBox.options[adultsSelectBox.selectedIndex].text;


console.log(adults);

// ...
// then ajax request etc..
```

Comment: thanks! - I already tried this, unfortunately this does not solve my problem

Comment: I tried it with just a couple values for testing and it did not work - but then I checked it for all dropdowns andit worked! - Thanks!